# Visual Studio 2022 not supporting python 3.64 bit

Tags: visual-studio

I have a problem with Visual Studio 2022, it says it doesn't support Python 3.64 bit. I searched which versions of Python are supported and when I searched to download it, it wasn't supported either. I need to submit an assignment (Python program) using Visual Studio and I don't have much time left, I need help please. Thanks

I tried to download the supported version of python which was Python 3.7 but it wasn't supported either, I can't understand what to do and where the problem is.